# Retrieve all Values of Checked Item in a custom Listview (Cursor Adapter)

Tags: android

Good day, am having a bit of trouble and have been stuck here for a while now. I am trying to get all the checked items from a custom listview (for now, just the number of checked items) and nothing seems to work. this code returns 0 and i don't know what to try anymore.

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

I have been able to successfully check and uncheck all the elements in the listview with this code:

```
  for(int i=0; i < list.getChildCount(); i++){  
  LinearLayout itemLayout= (LinearLayout)list.getChildAt(i);
  CheckBox checkbox =    (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.media_checkbox_id);
       checkbox.setChecked(true);           
}
```

but i can't seem to get the number of checked items at all!!!.. please any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem could be in ListItem layout.

It should implements Checkable to correct functioning of ListView's getCheckedItemPositions() and other similar functions.

Read [this](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/).

**Update:**

Here a code snippet from ListView.java source code:

```
if (mChoiceMode != CHOICE_MODE_NONE && mCheckStates != null) {
        if (child instanceof Checkable) {
            ((Checkable) child).setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position));
        }
    }
```

ListView doesn't know (or care) about the state of any checkbox inside your row. It simply asks to the row "are you checked?" or tells to the row, "please, set yourself checked!".

**So all "check using" functions from ListView are based in the premisse that your row (AKA child) is an instance of "checkable" view type.**

A checkable view tells to listview if the row is checked or not, and lets you control what to do when checked state changes (for example, by setting a checkbox state in your row).

Comment: is that not quite different, because i am not using checkedtextView. just wondering?...